# Jenkinsリモートホストシェル実行におけるAWS-S3への同期タイムアウト

Tags: jenkins, aws-cli

表題の通りで、Jenkinsからのリモートホストシェル実行時に
AWS CLIを利用してS3との同期を行うスクリプトをRUNしております。

スクリプト単体では問題なくAWSとの同期動作確認できているのですが
Jenkinsを経由（Hookトリガ）すると以下のようにタイムアウトが発生いたします。

```
fatal error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /xxx?prefix=&encoding-type=url (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x1686410>, 'Connection to xxx.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

また、リモートホスト上のシェル起動でなく、ローカルホスト上でのシェル起動でも同様の事象でした。

追記：

1. 問題のスクリプトを質問に追記できますか？
2. クレデンシャルはどのように指定していますか？

```sh
#　credentials パスを設定
export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=${cwd}/credentials/credentials
# config パスを設定
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=${cwd}/credentials/config
# sync 実行
aws s3 sync --profile ${aws_stage} --delete --exact-timestamps ${sync_src} ${sync_dest}
```

3. スクリプト単体で動かした場合と、Jenkinsのシェル起動した場合で、環境の違いはなんでしょうか？
   環境そのものの違いはありません。フックによるリモートシェル起動のトリガか、直接リモート先のスクリプトファイルを叩いているだけです。Jenkinsで同じスクリプトファイルをキックしています。

ご教授のほどよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Timeoutの場合、可能性としては多岐にわたるので、もう少し情報を追記してもらえると、回答できるかもしれません。さしあたっては、3点ほどありますので可能でしたら追記してみてもらえますか？ 1問題のスクリプトを質問に追記できますか？ 2 クレデンシャルはどのように指定していますか？ 3 スクリプト単体で動かした場合と、Jenkinsのシェル起動した場合で、環境の違いはなんでしょうか？

Comment: お時間割いてコメントくださりありがとうございます。下記にご指摘の3点に関する内容を記述いたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` と `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` のファイルは、Jenkinsの実行ユーザからの読み込み権限を許可してますか？

Comment: はい、リード権限等の付与は確認しました。また、”whoami"コマンドで実際のログインユーザの確認済みです。

Comment: 自己解決できました。色々、ご助言下さり’take88さん’ありがとうございました。原因はリモートアクセス（SSH）経由により、環境変数の反映がされないため、プロキシによるアクセス不可でした。。。直ぐに気づくべきでした・・・。’mijさん’文章の整形ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できました。色々とご助言下さり @take88 さんありがとうございました。

原因はリモートアクセス（SSH）経由により、環境変数の反映がされないため、プロキシによるアクセス不可でした。

---

この投稿は [@Nazonokusa さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47550/jenkins%e3%83%aa%e3%83%a2%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e3%83%9b%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%82%b7%e3%82%a7%e3%83%ab%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8a%e3%81%91%e3%82%8baws-s3%e3%81%b8%e3%81%ae%e5%90%8c%e6%9c%9f%e3%82%bf%e3%82%a4%e3%83%a0%e3%82%a2%e3%82%a6%e3%83%88#comment48895_47550) を元にコミュニティwikiとして投稿しました。